# Read Active Wifi 2.4 Ghz RFID tags android?

Tags: android, wifi, rfid

can anyone tell me if it is possible to read the new Active RFID tags with band same as wifi 2.4 ghz in Android or Java Smartphones?
some reference links for study will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. NFC (near field communications, the device in Android phones used to read RFID tags) operates on 13.56Mhz.

NFC: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Frequency-specific information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication

Comment: as they share same band as Wifi can't they be read using Wifi Module of some kind ??

Comment: *Some* RFID chips are the same band as wifi. However NFC chips are working on 13.56Mhz, which is very far away on the spectrum from 2.4Ghz. Therefore, you cannot use an NFC-enabled device (on 13.56Mhz) to communicate with an RFID chip on the 2.4Ghz band.

Comment: i am not asking about NFC enabled device
rather simply 
is it possible to read that RFID using any Wifi Chip as they have have same band (even home Wifi Routers will do ) ??

Comment: Uhmm, no. That's not how it works. That's like asking if you can use the internet with your hair dryer because it plugs into the wall just like your computer. Here's a good read about the basics: http://www.connect802.com/rfid_facts.htm